# R data.table: Sum column with multiple values per row

Tags: r, sum, data.table, unique-values

I have a dataset that has columns with semi-colon separated values that represent countries like this:

```
row countries weights
1: 22;3 1.254
2: 5 0.54
3: 6;8;123 2.65
4: 16 0.35
5: 77;21;1 0.98
6: 89 1.74
etc.
```

with data.tables, I can sum per unique values like this:

```
dt[!is.na(countries),.(sum(weights)), by= countries]
```

This gives me this:

```
              countries V1
   1:                 2 791.243
   2:               230  10.644
   3:                50   4.517
   4:                 1 544.056
   5:        1;75;77;91   0.370
```

The problem is that the semi-colon separated values are not splitted to their unique values. What I want is a sum per unique value in the column so that the result contains no more semi-colon separated values.

How can I split the column up and then build the sum per unique value?

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-string-column-and-insert-as-multiple-new-rows) helpful

Comment: thanks to both of you! this `out <- d.dt[, list(V2 = unlist(strsplit(V2, ","))), by=V1]`did the trick