# R - dplyr - create duplicate row by spliting one column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a data that has a structure looking like `df` below, but I need to turn that into `df2`. Is there a function in the `tidyverse` that can do this?

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("a", "a b", "a b c"))
df2 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,2,3,3,3), y = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df %>% separate_rows(y)` per the first couple of results when googling for your question title - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37979009/496803