# Import CSV with R, where second variable in CSV file is a list

Tags: r, list, csv, import, stack

I am trying to import a CSV file with R, and am having trouble.

The CSV entries look like

```
"Name 1" , "Name 2, Name 3, Name 4"
```

If I import straight to R, the data is read in like

```
Name 1     Name 2,Name 3,Name 4
```

but I would like it to look like

```
Name 1     Name 2
Name 1     Name 3
Name 1     Name 4
```

Is there a way to break up the second column during import so I can have two columns with only one name in each?

Thanks

Comment: That's not a valid string.  Please give the `read.csv` code as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows

Answer (score 0):

Use `strsplit` to break the column up into an actual `list` class, then use `tidyr::unnest` to get your result:

```
d = data.frame(a = "Name 1" , b = "Name 2, Name 3, Name 4")
d$b = strsplit(d$b, ",")
library(tidyr)
unnest(d)
#        a       b
# 1 Name 1  Name 2
# 2 Name 1  Name 3
# 3 Name 1  Name 4
```

Depending on how clean things are, you might need to trim whitespace of the new column, see `?trimws` for help there.

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much!