# How can I use dplyr to split strings within a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a good understanding of how I would do this in another computer language, but am having trouble using the dplyr package in R to accomplish this task. I have a tbl dataset that has a column of data, Dip1, that contains strings with names of banks separated by semicolons. Example:

```
Number  Dip1  

1       Goldman Sachs; Morgan Stanley
2       UBS; Wells Fargo; Wachovia
3       Bank of America
4
```

How can I use dplyr to split the strings of the column by the ";"? This is intuitive in other languages by indexing the column and iterating through the rows and splicing by ";", but I am not sure if iteration is needed in this case using dplyr. Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer:

```
require(tidyr)
tbl2 <- tbl %>% separate(Dip1, 
        sep = "; ", 
        into = c("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: This answer should have `library(tidyr)` and a space in the `sep` argument

Comment: When used in this way, `require(tidyr)` accomplishes the same thing as `library(tidyr)`.   The second is more common, but the first is acceptable.  Execute `?require` at the prompt to learn more.