# Splitting a single column into multiple columns

Tags: r, regex

I need to split a dataframe into multiple columns to make sure only one value is contained within each cell. The current dataframe looks like:

```
 projectid|  count | Name |  Type                         |   count   |
 .....................................................................
 ABC      |  211   | jack |abc(Apple, Orange, Water melon)|   Multiple|
 DBG      | 90     | jill | Plum                          |   single  |
```

The new dataframe should look like

```
 projectid|  count | Name |  Type          |  count |
 ....................................................
 ABC      |  211   | jack |  Apple         |Multiple|
 ABC      |  211   | jack |  Orange        |Multiple|
 ABC      |  211   | jack |  Water melon   |Multiple|
 DBG      |  90    | jill |  Plum          |single  |
```

I can split the single cell using regular expression based on the "()" and "," as a separator. However, I can't figure out how to populate multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to extract everything between brackets and then use `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Type = sub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", Type)) %>%
  separate_rows(Type, sep = ",")

#  projectid count Name         Type  count.1
#1       ABC   211 jack        Apple Multiple
#2       ABC   211 jack       Orange Multiple
#3       ABC   211 jack  Water melon Multiple
#4       DBG    90 jill         Plum   single
```

The main part is the regex to extract everything in between round brackets. Once we do that we can use any of the method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows) link to separate comma-separated value in different rows.

Comment: Minor edit needed as the ‘Water melon’ is a single word.

Comment: @Arihant Sorry, missed that. Use `sep = ','` in `separate_rows`. Updated the answer.