# Dividing rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I would like to divide rows in R in certain columns.. in my example, I would like to make a new row every time there is a `\n`.

Any ideas? Preferably, I would like to do that using `tidyverse`.

**Reprex:**

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(
  x = c("Row 1", "Row 2\nRow 3", "Row 4"),
  y = c("Value 1", "Value 2\nValue 3", "Value 4")
)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   x              y                 
#>   <chr>          <chr>             
#> 1 Row 1          Value 1           
#> 2 "Row 2\nRow 3" "Value 2\nValue 3"
#> 3 Row 4          Value 4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Desired output**:

```r
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   x     y
#>   <chr> <chr>                                          
#> 1 Row 1 Value 1                                        
#> 2 Row 2 Value 2                                        
#> 3 Row 3 Value 3                                        
#> 4 Row 4 Value 4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-strings-in-a-column-into-separate-rows)

Comment: Well made question that seems to be a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `separate_rows` with `sep = "\n"`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   separate_rows(x, y, sep = "\n")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  x     y      
#  <chr> <chr>  
#1 Row 1 Value 1
#2 Row 2 Value 2
#3 Row 3 Value 3
#4 Row 4 Value 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(
  x = c("Row 1", "Row 2\nRow 3", "Row 4"),
  y = c("Value 1", "Value 2\nValue 3", "Value 4")
)
```