# Splitting columns with different number of elements into rows

Tags: tidyr

I'm working with a bioinformatics tool called OrthoFinder, which puts genes from different genomes/species into what are called Orthogroups based on sequences similarity.

One of the output files tells you which genes are in which Orthogroup. Here, the first column has the Orthogroup ID. The next three columns represent three genomes. In the genome columns each row contains the IDs of  genes that fit in each Orthogroup. If there are multiple genes within an Orthogroup for each genome, than the algorithm put the genes in a list separated by commas.

| Orthogroup | genome1 | genome2 | genome3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OG0000001 | gene1, gene2, gene 3 |  | gene1 |
| OG0000002 |  | gene5, gene6 | gene4 |
| OG0000003 | gene7 | gene7, gene8 |  |

I want to separate the data in the columns containing gene IDs so that each gene gets its own row. Easy peasy, right? Here are some links on how to do that with strsplit(), tidyr:seperate(rows), and the newer tidyr:seperate_longer_delim()

[Split delimited strings in a column and insert as new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows)

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_longer_delim.html

The issue is that I'm having are that each column has a different number of genes. In my table above, you can see in the second row, OG0000002, that genome1 contains nothing. So, if I use strplit() based on genome1, I loose OG0000002, along with the gene IDs in genome2 and genome3.

When I try

```
separate_longer_delim(c(genome1, genome2, genome3), delim=",")
```

I get an error like this:

```
Error in `separate_longer_delim()`:
! In row 2, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 5.
```

Here's what Hadley Wickham had to say about this error: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1505

I need a way to separate elements in each column but not drop rows if there are a different number of genes in each row.

This is one of my first posts of stackoverflow, so I don't have much experience explaining my code in this format. Please be kind and I will do my best to clarify. In the meantime, I will continue to troubleshoot and post any updates.

tl;dr- I want each gene to have its own rows. I tried strsplit and separate_longer_delim.

Comment: Did you manage to test this on your full dataset? Curious to know the outcome. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for following up. I got side-tracked with another project. I just tried your suggested code with a large data set and it worked with no issues. Thank you again for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, this will work and *should* scale up to your full dataset if the data are consistent across all columns. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll update my answer.

This solution uses the `cSplit()` function from the `splitstackshape` package. I have assumed your blank values are NAs, and that "gene 2" was meant to be "gene3". Either way, this method will work:

```r
library(splitstackshape)

# Your sample data
df <- data.frame(Orthogroup = c("OG0000001", "OG0000002", "OG0000003"),
                 genome1 = c("gene1, gene2, gene3", NA, "gene1"),
                 genome2 = c(NA, "gene5, gene6", "gene4"),
                 genome3 = c("gene7", "gene7, gene8", NA))

# Pivot to long format
df1 <- data.frame(cSplit(df,
                         names(df[2:ncol(df)]), # All columns except the first one 
                         ",", #Delimiter
                         "long", # Rowise/long format
                         type.convert = "as.character")) # Value type

df1
  Orthogroup genome1 genome2 genome3
1  OG0000001   gene1    <NA>   gene7
2  OG0000001   gene2    <NA>    <NA>
3  OG0000001   gene3    <NA>    <NA>
4  OG0000002    <NA>   gene5   gene7
5  OG0000002    <NA>   gene6   gene8
6  OG0000002    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
7  OG0000003   gene1   gene4    <NA>
8  OG0000003    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
9  OG0000003    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Ah heck yeah! This looks great! I'll try it out on my data frame that has 28 columns in the next day or so and let you know how it goes :D